# If it possible to compress angular2 Js bundle files further

Tags: angular, gruntjs

Does anyone have any idea on additional ways to compress the generated production `Angular` Js files?

Here is what am currently doing...

1. ng build --prod
2. grunt

   - concat all files in order of output
   - uglify concatenated js file

I have managed to get it down to around 1.2mb from the above but I would ideally get it down to under a meg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to improve your compression could be to build using the [AOT](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) flag (`--aot`) which will again, reduce the size of your bundle.

Also, don't forget that the file will be compressed with `gzip` by your server and will, in the end, weight not as much as `300ko`, which is something pretty decent for your whole application. :)